# OutPan Question

Tags: barcodes

I have managed to build a VB.Net app to look up UPC/EAN codes on OutPan, but cannot get it to accept my attempts to add new items. My url is ...

https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/9300617041207/Cadbury+Crunchie?apikey=[MyAPIkey]

Clearly, I have this malformed. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Jeff Law

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://www.outpan.com/developers you have to use `POST` request which contains `name` field in the parameters.

And the url should be:
`https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/9300617041207/name?apikey=[MyAPIkey]`

request example:
`curl -X POST -d "name=some_product" https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/9300617041207/name?apikey=[MyAPIkey]`

Comment: Are you saying that the word 'name' is replaced with the Name value?

Comment: Re my previous comment, I tried that with no success. I also tried 'name=[Name]' with success.
I suggest that the documentation is somewhat light on detail.

Comment: No the word 'name' should not be replaced with anything. The second format you are trying to pass is `GET` parameter. I have added an example to my answer, hope it helps (Maybe this link will explain it http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in the answer(s).
I am trying to add a [Name] to an existing item in the database.
In other words, the item already exists, and I want to now update it with it's Name.

Comment: Now I'm making progress - to add an Attribute, my POST data is 'name=[AttributeName]&value=[AttributeValue]' and this works as expected.
However, I cannot fathom the POST data to add a [Name].
I have tried 'name=[Name]' and 'value=[Name]' but these return an error response.

Comment: Finally, I have it sorted - persistence pays off.
Now, I just need to find a way to update a [NAME] which has been incorrectly entered!

Comment: is outpan even active now? We had an integration with outpan API last year, but now the website itself is down. Anybody have an idea if they are closed or moved to a new address?